# Views Data Export Permissions Problem

Tags: 7, views

I have [Views Data Export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export) installed, which creates a CSV file attached to every node. This file has all of the data from a field collection field arranged as a CSV.

The only user that should be able to download this CSV file is the admin (user 1) and the user that created the node.

In Views Data Export, I can select Role as a permission, and assign it to all "Managers", but that means each "Manager" can download other Managers data if they get the URL right. Anyone wanting to maliciously steal data, or sneak a peak at how much their colleagues are earning can simply guess the URL of the CSV file.

How would I restrict this download to the author of the node?

I have tried installing [Path Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathrules), and creating a Rule that checks that the path of the CSV ends with CSV, and then runs a condition to check that the Nid of the currently logged in user matches one created by the author, but the download happens automatically regardless. There doesnt seem to be a path check before it is downloaded.

Stuck here scratching my head, would welcome even the slightest suggestion, or just a fresh pair of eyes! Thanks.

**OK, some progression...**

I delved into creating a views custom access like so...

Added `files[] = couples_page_custom_access_plugin.inc` to a custom module info file

Added the following to couples_page_custom_access_plugin.inc

```
<?php

  /**
   * Access plugin that provides property based access control.
   */
  class couples_page_custom_access_plugin extends views_plugin_access {

    function summary_title() {
      return t('Couples Page Check User is Author');
    } // summary_title()

  /**
   * Determine if the current user has access or not.
   */
    function access($account) {    
      return couples_page_custom_access($account);
    }

    function get_access_callback() {
      return array('couples_page_custom_access', array()); 
    }

  }
```

Then added this to a custom module...

```
  function couples_page_custom_views_plugins() {
    $plugins = array(
      'access' => array(
        'test' => array(
          'title' => t('Couples Page Check User is Author'),
          'help' => t('this is a custom access plugin'),
          'handler' => 'couples_page_custom_access_plugin',
          'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'couples_page_custom'),
        ),
      ),
    );
    return $plugins;
  }

  function couples_page_custom_access($account = NULL) {
    global $user;
    $access = false; 
    $account = user_load($user->uid);
    $node = node_load(arg(1)); // Get the nid from the URL of the CSV file.

    // If the UID of the currently logged in user matches the UID of the node author return true.
    if ($account == $node->uid) {
      $access = true; 
    }
    return $access;

  }
```

But its not really working. If I set $access = true it works, and $access = false, it doesnt, so I know the plugin is working. It must be the logic in the last bit here...

```
function couples_page_custom_access($account = NULL) {
        global $user;
        $access = false; 
        $account = user_load($user->uid);
        $node = node_load(arg(1)); // Get the nid from the URL of the CSV file.

        // If the UID of the currently logged in user matches the UID of the node author return true.
        if ($account == $node->uid) {
          $access = true; 
        }
        return $access;

      }
```

Perhaps I am not getting the author uid of that node correctly? I will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

I was using user_load() in an earlier example, and was still using it rather than the uid.

The final access check should be...

```
function couples_page_custom_access($account = NULL) {
    global $user;
    $access = false; 
    $node = node_load(arg(1)); // Get the nid from the URL of the CSV file.

    // If the UID of the currently logged in user matches the UID of the node author return true.
    if ($user->uid == $node->uid) {
      $access = true; 
    }
    // Else check if the current user is admin so we can download what we like.
if (in_array('Admin', $user->roles)) {
  $access = true;
}
    return $access;

  }
```

I also added a check to return true if the current user is an Admin.

I really hope this helps someone else, and saves the time it took me to get to this!

Still, every days a school day!